# Waiting for all the async ajax calls to complete with deferred.when().then(), task in then() not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I Have a following method that makes ajax call and this method gets called multiple times from another function, so that ends up making multiple ajax async call. I need to perform certain task only after all the async ajax call finishes.

```
var makeAjaxCall = function() {
var ret = new $.Deferred();
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      //do stuff
      ret.resolve(data);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
     // do stuff
    })
    .always(function() {
      //do stuff
    });

    return ret;
  };
```

And this function gets called from for loops that iterates through object.

```
var items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  for (var i = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    makeAjaxCall();
}
```

Now i am  performing a task that waits until all the triggered ajax call finishes.

```
$.when(makeAjaxCall()).then(function(ret) {
        // perform the task
      });
```

The issue is, the 'then' part in the deferred.when() does not get called and that task is not performed. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` already returns a promise that is resolved when it completes successfully, so you don't need an additional deferred. Just `return $.ajax`.

On top of that `$.when` accepts variadic arguments -- all deferreds, but not an array. If you want to use an array you have to use `.apply`.

```
var arrayOfPromises = items.map(item => {
    // Do you need to pass in `item` or something?
    return makeAjaxCall();
});
$.when.apply($, arrayOfPromises).then(() => {
    // perform task
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, its not working.Not sure what i'm missing.

Comment: This is my first time coding in jquery, so pardon me if my questions sounds silly. The ajax calls that i make will not succeed all the time, there are chances of failures. So i still wanted the task in the when().then() to be performed irrespective of whether it succeeded or not. For debugging purpose, i had failure callback in the then(), still it doesn't get hit.